# enemy won't follow player. SDL2/C++

Tags: c++, sdl

So I was looking through the forums and found formula which should make, let's say, enemy follow the player. However, when I run my program the enemy starts walking but not to the player's direction. No matter where I place my character, the enemy kinda walks straight downwards. Here's the code:

```
void Enemy::enemyMovement(SDL_Rect& passed_player_rect, int speed){

player_rect = passed_player_rect;

dirx = player_rect.x - enemy_rect.x;
diry = player_rect.y - enemy_rect.y;

hyp = sqrt(dirx*dirx + diry*diry);

dirx /=hyp;
diry /=hyp;

enemy_rect.x += dirx * speed;
enemy_rect.y += diry * speed;
}
```

Comment: Please submit code that compiles.

Comment: How do you return enemy_rect? Is it a class member variable? Please include all the variable definitions, so that we know their type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the approximation from floating point to integer, which is especially visible if your speed is low. You should make sure that:

1. `dirx` and `diry` are floating point
2. You keep player and enemy
   positions stored in floating point variables, you do all computations and update new positions using these variables
3. At every movement you update *visualization* in the *integer position* stored in SDL_Rect structures doing a rounding operation based on current/updated value of variables described at point 2

Answer (score 0):

You always render with int positions (can't be half pixels), but on entity positions you must use float, unless the acceleration is greater that 1/-1 (motion of 1 px / update).

```
struct Body {
float x,y;
float velX,velY;
}


Body body;        //at your entity class
```

Enemy loop:

```
body.x += body.velX;    //and these are floats
body.y += body.velY;
```

ps. Don't use:

```
int speed
```

use

```
float speed
```